# Cluster Shared Volume - SQL - Failover Cluster Nodes

Tags: sql-server, powershell, cluster-computing

In WFC a shared disk device has a dependency on a cluster resource like SQL Server. With the introduction of Cluster Shared Volumes (CSV) this dependency isn't there any longer because we assume that a CSV is always there.

That's right (sometimes), but if a SAN failure happens, the CSV or several volumes presenting the CSV will be gone and SQL Server will start again. This brings SQL Server in an unpredictable situation and happened.

So we like to have a PowerShell script (running on every node on the cluster) monitoring the CSV and stopping the group hosting the SQL resources if CSV failures happen.

Comment: You've not shown any of your own code or any indication you've tried researching/searching for a solution. (Always include your code even if it doesn't work!) I'd recommend reading [ask] and the [question checklist](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260648/stack-overflow-question-checklist) as at the moment your question is missing the basics that are expected when asking a question. Your question is likely to be downvoted and closed until you include the basics.

Comment: are You sure it's not possible to have some kind of dependency configured for Your sql service inside failover cluster? maybe You can add it manually? sorry do not have failover cluster with CSV at hand to check - I've checked that I can manually add dependency on any other part of same resource group  - maybe it's same for CSV ?